# GNU C : How can I compile a C program with dynamic library option -lmylib but without -L option

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, ld, dynamic-library

I have used several libraries for example `pthread` as `-lpthread` and `math` as `-lmath` but I need not use the `-L` option to specify linking path.

But,

1. I created a library `mylib` by compiling my program `mylib.c` as
   `gcc -fPIC mylib.c -o libmylib.so`
2. placed it in `/usr/local/lib/libcustom`
3. Added path `/usr/local/lib/libcustom` into a file
   `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libcustom.conf`
4. run `ldconfig`
5. run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/customlib`
6. created a `sample.c` called the function in `mylib`

Now when I compile `sample.c` a `gcc -L /usr/local/lib/customlib -o sample.o -lmylib` it work fine where as when I try `gcc sample.c -o sample.o -lmylib` it gives ld error as `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib`

I want to know why is `-L` flag optional in case of `-lpthread` and mandatory in case of `-lmylib`? How can I skip the use of `-L` in case of `-lmylib`?

Thanks.

Comment: Try "ldconfig -p | grep -i mylib" to check that your library stored in current cache

Comment: because the system (linker) already knows where to find `libpthread` but doesn't know where to look for `libmylib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `LIBRARY_PATH`.

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for loading dynamic libraries at *runtime*, not compile time.

---

Side note: when adding on to existing environment variables, make sure to use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of just `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Otherwise, you're discarding the original contents and putting in the literal text `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

So it should change from:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/customlib
```

to:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/customlib
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution where my custom library stays distinguishable from system libraries as well as linker automatically identifies the library.

Comment: `LIBRARY_PATH` is what you're looking for, then :)

Answer (score 1):

For this reason you need to have mylib placed in the paths known to the linker. For example somewhere like /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. In your case it works with `pthread` because it is already located in the system known paths.